# Calling Soap Webservice (made in C#) from java

Tags: java, authentication, soap, wsse

Below is the code that I've tried to call the service

```
public class TestClient {

    private static final String WS_URL = 
            "http://host.ca/Service.svc?wsdl";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("calling service...");
        URL url = new URL(WS_URL);
        QName qname = new QName(
            "http://test.org/",
            "TestXmlService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        ITestXmlService hello = service.getPort(ITestXmlService.class);

        // The BindingProvider interface provides
        //access to the protocol binding and
        // to the associated context objects
        //for request and response message processing.
        BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) hello;
        Map<String, Object> req_ctx = provider.getRequestContext();
        req_ctx.put(
        BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, WS_URL);
System.out.println("ahsgahdh");
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("username"));
        headers.put("Password",
            Collections.singletonList("password"));
        req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
System.out.println("tst...: "+headers.toString());
        GetMessageListRequestItemWrapper req1  = new GetMessageListRequestItemWrapper();
        System.out.println("123114");
        try
        {

            System.out.println("dshjfvdj: "+hello.getMessageList(req1));
        }
        catch(Exception e)

        {
            System.out.println("error..  "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

It gives me error when calling the getMessageList service.The service is hosted on IIS and uses a certificate and user/password to authenticate. So is this the correct way to call this service. The error that I get when executing the above code is as below:

```
calling service...
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedSupportingTokens" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SymmetricBinding" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Trust10" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Wss11" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}UsingAddressing" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedSupportingTokens" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SymmetricBinding" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Trust10" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Wss11" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}UsingAddressing" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}SignedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Sep 24, 2016 1:52:31 PM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
ahsgahdh
tst...: {Password=[T1@P4vtiXce9], Username=[vha-test.xml]}
123114
error..  java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a SOAP client. Turns out I was missing webservices-rt.jar